# How much accuracy does 2to3 Python module has to convert files?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, module, python-2to3

I have whole project to convert from Python 2.x to 3.x. So can I go ahead & convert it by just 2to3 module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said that you have to convert whole module there can be some warnings and some errors but they still refactoring is possible. For reference you can always go to "https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#module-lib2to3" and "https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html".

Comment: What if didn't get any errors ? Does that mean my python file is successfully converted.

Comment: Better to use static type checker as in mypy("http://mypy-lang.org/") or pytype (https://github.com/google/pytype) in your code and ensure that every function serves the purpose expected in both versions of python.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can. maybe there will be some errors but it generly it will be going well

Comment: So i tried using with multiple files. It worked fine with some modifications done by 2to3 Lib. But how can i test the script if that is successfully converted or not. As it is almost 1000 lines of code in it.

Comment: just run it. if there are errors you will find them

Comment: and os_sys has a module os_sys.doc_maker.helper.HTMLdoc(path to folder with files)

Comment: it not only doc but also test